# Link tables together

Tags: mysql

I want to link 2 tables togheter, but my second table has more than one value.

First table:

```
Partnumber | description | type
100          blabla        blabla
```

second table:

```
Partnumber | item number
100          500
100          600
200          0
```

now i want to link the tables together on partnumber but all the item numbers must go in the same record. and there can be more item numbers on a part number.

result:

```
partnumber | description | type    | item number
100          blabla        blabla    500,600
```

is it possible to show it that way? in one line?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use the `group_concat` function

```
select partnumber, description, type, group_concat(coalesce(item_number, "No items"))
from table1 a
left join table2 b using(partnumber)
group by partnumber;
```